# SwashBuckle/Swagger is hiding my immutable properties

Tags: c#, swagger, swashbuckle

For models that get passed into actions via `[FromBody]` I like to make their properties immutable `public int SomeProperty { get; private set; }`. This way I know the input to my handler isn't modified.

The problem I'm having is that Swagger and Swashbuckle are completely ignoring those fields for rendering examples of parameter payloads. I looked at the swagger schema that was generated from our API and saw that all of the mentioned fields have `readOnly: true`.

I'm wondering if there is some way to configure Swashbuckler or Swagger to not ignore these properties. Or maybe there is some way to just set readonly to false for each definition using some part of SwashBuckle's extension framework?

Edit: Adding sample from swagger.json

On this example someProperty is marked readOnly. I think that is why the property doesn't show up in the generated example of a POST parameter. If there is a way to make swagger gen not add any readonly properties I'd be fine with that.

```
{
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "someProperty": {
      "format": "int32",
      "type": "integer",
      "readOnly": true
    },
  }
}
```

Comment: Maybe this will help https://www.codemag.com/article/1905041

Comment: Can you share your swagger.json, or at least the relevant portion of what you have now and what you would like to get?

Comment: @HelderSepulveda I added an example. I think what I want is that same structure but without the readonly.

Comment: What version of swashbuckle are you using?
I see than on latest of Swashbuckle.AspNetCore they have unit tests covering those cases:  
https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore/blob/a40ecca0be4dc78b46642d68201dccef512a8c73/test/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen.Test/SchemaGen/SchemaGeneratorTests.cs#L207

Comment: Those test cases are testing that swashbuckle does the opposite of what I want.. Maybe I need to approach immutability differently if there is no way to turn that feature off.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

So I found a solution. I created an ISchemaFilter implementation that just sets readonly on each property to false. I need to think more about what this implies downstream, so I'm not sure if I like the solution yet.

```
public class IgnoreReadOnlySchemaFilter : ISchemaFilter
{
    public void Apply(Schema schema, SchemaFilterContext context)
    {
        schema.ReadOnly = false;
        if (schema.Properties != null)
        {
            foreach (var keyValuePair in schema.Properties)
            {
                keyValuePair.Value.ReadOnly = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Accepting my own answer because it's possible to add extra sophistication here by using attributes and inspecting them. I decided if I ever want readonly fields I'll add a `SwaggerReadOnly` attribute and consume it in this SchemaFilter to avoid setting the field's readonly property to false.

Comment: Thanks, saved my night.

Comment: This worked for most cases, but doesn't work for enum or Class properties (reference properties). Seems like we would need to use "UseAllOfToExtendReferencedSchemas", but I haven't found a good example of using that to get the same expected readonly result.